# Add jquery inside PHP file

Tags: php, jquery

I am having a hard time trying to insert jquery code inside my PHP file. This is what I have so far.

```
</div>
<!-- left -->
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
  <div id="rightside">
    <img src="images/about/ab1.jpg" style="margin-left: 30px;">
  </div>
```

This particular code is what I want to fade in when user scrolls down.

Comment: You should describe problem elaborately. What you really want, what portion can you complete...

Answer (score 2):

It's nothing to do with PHP, you can treat it with HTML as usual.
So, you don't need to "insert" into PHP.

---

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $(window).scroll(function () {
                    $("#rightside").fadeOut();
                });
               
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="rightside">
            <img src="images/about/ab1.jpg" style="margin-left: 30px;">
        </div>

       
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! That helps a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Inside your php file

```
<script>

    var lastScrollTop = 0;
    $(window).scroll(function(event){
       var st = $(this).scrollTop();
       if (st > lastScrollTop){
           $('img').fadeIn();
       }
       lastScrollTop = st;
    });

</script>
```